# adding url link in a function

Tags: php, hyperlink

This is probably an easy fix, but I am new to this.  I have some code from a previous developer and I have been asked to edit the text for the email that gets sent out.  I have tried using a regular href tag but that doesnt work.  Is there a specific way to add a URL in the example below?  It is the Ready to get started line.  The click should be hyperlinked.  Thanks!!

```
function send_info_kit(){
        if($_POST):
        $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_info']);
        $q = "INSERT INTO rog_info_requesters(`email`) VALUES('{$to}')";
        $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
        print $to;

        $from ='support@reachingourgoal.org';
        $name = 'Reaching Our Goal';
        $subject='Info kit you requested';
        $message=nl2br('Information on America’s best fundraising program for sports teams and 
        school groups is attached.

Finally, a modern process that generates thousands of dollars in profit and 
takes just minutes to launch.

A few reasons why www.rechingourgoal.org is the right choice:

- Takes minutes
- No selling    
- 80% Profits   
- Online tracking
- We do the work

Ready to get started now?  http://www.reachingourgoal.org"Click!

Text ROG to 9192835123. Get clued in on amazing results and success tips.

We are helping people like you do amazing things every day.

Reaching Our Goal
www.ReachingOurGoal.org
');
        $cc='';
        $bcc='junk@reachingourgoal.org,jon@mysportsdreams.com';
        //$attach='http://www.reachingourgoal.org/assets/images/ReachingOurGoalInfoKit.pdf';
        $file = FCPATH .'/assets/images/ROGFreeInfo.pdf';

        if(file_exists($file)):
        {
            echo "File exists. Path ok: " . $file;
        }
        else:
        {
            echo "Cannot find file: " . $file;
        }
        endif;
        $this->member->send_info($to,$from,$name ,$subject,$message,$cc,$bcc,$file);
        endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $message=nl2br('Information on America’s best fundraising program for sports teams and 
        school groups is attached.

Finally, a modern process that generates thousands of dollars in profit and 
takes just minutes to launch.

A few reasons why www.rechingourgoal.org is the right choice:

- Takes minutes
- No selling    
- 80% Profits   
- Online tracking
- We do the work

Ready to get started now?  <a href="http://www.reachingourgoal.org">Click!</a>

Text ROG to 9192835123. Get clued in on amazing results and success tips.

We are helping people like you do amazing things every day.

Reaching Our Goal
www.ReachingOurGoal.org
');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like following,

```
$message = 'string <a href="http://Domain.com">!click</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
http://www.reachingourgoal.org"Click!
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.reachingourgoal.org">Click!</a>
```

does the job.